# How to find out username of laptop with python?

Tags: python, file, directory

I want to Open a file located inside a folder, that is in the same directory as the python script.

For example:

- main.py
- image_folder

  - image_1
  - image_2
  - image_3

Right now i would type `open(image_1.png)`, or I would type `open(C:\Users\user_name\Desktop\main_folder\image_folder\image_1)`.
But i would wish to make it so that the user name doesn't need to be filled out for a different user.

Is there a simple way to open a file inside a folder in the same directory as the script file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do the following:

```
import os

username = os.getlogin()
```

So that the username your signed in to comes up.

Then you could replace `user_name` with the username variable.

Comment: Depending on what you are doing, it would be much easier to do this as a batch file from what you have shown

Comment: I will look into that, it looks like it could help me for this and future projects.